How to restore a single window in KDE after show desktop was enabled?
I am using KDE Plasma in Kubuntu 24.04.
I have enabled hot corner to show the desktop, which minimizes all the running apps.
After I click on an app at this point, this maximizes all the other apps.
In Windows, or in Cinnamon, the behavior is, only the app which is opened is shown, all other apps stay minimized. How to enable this behavior in KDE Plasma?

You can switch the behavior to Windows-like mode:
Edit panel > right-click on Show Desktop icon > Show Alternatives... > Minimize All Windows
